# Why does Three.js animation not work on a <div> but it does on the <body>?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I put a Three.js animation on the `body`, it works perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I try to put it inside a `div`.

The only thing I changed in the JS file versus that version where Three.js animation is put on the `body` is this line:

- `document.body.appendChild(container);`
- `document.getElementById('for_three').appendChild(container);`

If I change `document.getElementById('for_three').appendChild(container);` back to `document.body.appendChild(container);` in the JS file and delete `<div id="for_three"></div>` in the HTML file, then Three.js animation is put on the `body` and works perfectly fine.

*Note: I couldn't create a snippet because the post was too long, but the code is exactly the same as [this](https://codepen.io/deathfang/pen/WxNVoq) one.*

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Three.js animation</title>
            <style>
                body { margin: 0; }
            </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="three.js"></script>

            <div id="for_three"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#for_three {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-left: 25%;
        background-color: bisque;
}
```

**JS:**

```
// three.js - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js

var SEPARATION = 100,
    AMOUNTX = 100,
    AMOUNTY = 70;
 
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
 
var particles, particle, count = 0;
 
var mouseX = 85,
    mouseY = -342;
 
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
 
init();
animate();
 
function init() {
 
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById('for_three').appendChild(container);
 
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(120, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 1000;
 
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
 
    particles = new Array();
 
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var material = new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial({
 
        color: 0x000000,
        program: function(context) {
 
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0, 0, .6, 0, PI2, true);
            context.fill();
 
        }
 
    });
 
    var i = 0;
 
    for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
 
        for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
 
            particle = particles[i++] = new THREE.Particle(material);
            particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTX * SEPARATION) / 2);
            particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTY * SEPARATION) / 2);
            scene.add(particle);
 
        }
 
    }
 
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
 
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 
}
 
function onWindowResize() {
 
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
 
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 
}
 
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
 
    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
 
}
 
function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
 
    if (event.touches.length === 1) {
 
        event.preventDefault();
 
        mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
 
    }
 
}
 
function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {
 
    if (event.touches.length === 1) {
 
        event.preventDefault();
 
        mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
 
    }
 
}
 
function animate() {
 
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 
    render();
 
}
 
function render() {
 
    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
    camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 
    var i = 0;
 
    for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
 
        for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
 
            particle = particles[i++];
            particle.position.y = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) * 50) + (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) * 50);
            particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) + 1) * 2 + (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) + 1) * 2;
 
        }
 
    }
 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
 
    count += 0.1;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing your script **before** the `<div id="for_three"></div>` has been created in the document. So when your script tries to find the div, it doesn't exist yet. This is because the browser reads your HTML from top to bottom. Just change the order so your `<script>` tag is at the end of the document:

```
<body>
    <div id="for_three"></div>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
</body>
```